# Remove File with Space in Filename ios

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

I want to remove an image for Documents Directory. The image has this `2016-06-08 12:24:55.897image.jpg` kind of naming convention.

Code Snippet

```
-(void) removeImageAtPath:(NSString *) filePath{
NSError *error;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
BOOL success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
if (success) {
    NSLog(@"Image Successfully Deleted");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Could not delete file -:%@ ",[error localizedDescription]);
}
}
```

Error Code
`NSCocoaErrorDomain Code = 4`

I know the error comes when the file is not found. Which is happening because of the naming convention i have used.
I cannot change the convention. Is there any way to still remove the file.

Answer (score 0):

this code remove directly file name

```
 - (void)removeImage:(NSString *)filename
    {
      NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
      NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

      NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
      NSError *error;
      BOOL success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
      if (success) {
          UIAlertView *removedSuccessFullyAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congratulations:" message:@"Successfully removed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
          [removedSuccessFullyAlert show];
      }
      else
      {
          NSLog(@"Could not delete file -:%@ ",[error localizedDescription]);
      }
    }
```

other wise use this code

```
NSError *error;
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] isDeletableFileAtPath:path]) {
    BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Error removing file at path: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}
```

can you please try this code

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
BOOL fileExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path];
NSLog(@"Path to file: %@", path);        
NSLog(@"File exists: %d", fileExists);
NSLog(@"Is deletable file at path: %d", [fileManager isDeletableFileAtPath:path]);
if (fileExists) 
{
    BOOL success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:path error:&error];
    if (!success) NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: tried, same error `Could not delete file -:“2016-06-08 12/52/16.326image” couldn’t be removed.` `NSError * domain: @"NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code: 4 `

Comment: for the second code. It goes inside the if clause `if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] isDeletableFileAtPath:path]) ` but gives the same error after that.

Comment: is there any way to escape the characters in filename and then delete.

Comment: NSCocoaErrorDomain Code = 4  means that you are trying to move a file that does not exist, this could also mean that the target directory does not exists.

Comment: none of those helped. I went with naming the images without special characters. That solved it.